# Are Heavy Balls better for catching legendaries than Timer Balls?

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver

Heavy balls increase catch rate by +20 to +40 for heavy pokemon. This seems much better than increasing rate by 4* as catch rate of all legendaries is 3. To top it off, legendaries are usually quite heavy.

So why do people use timer balls instead? Is it that Heavy balls are tough to obtain in the game? Am I missing something?

Comment: In which games? GSC or HGSS?

Comment: HGSS. Why in the world does it have an ORAS Description entry thingimajig? Side question: why aren't so many awesome 2nd gen things (Heavy Ball, Berserk gene, etc.) available in 6th Gen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** Yes, *Heavy Balls* are usually better than *Timer Balls* for catching legendaries.

The multiplier depends on the catch rate of the pokémon as well as the weight of the heavy pokémon. In a few cases, for very heavy pokémon, you get a better multiplier than even the 8x *Level Ball* or *Love Ball*.

Note that when a Heavy Ball is thrown at any pokémon weighting at least 451.5lbs, it always gives a better than 1x chance of catching the pokémon, but for pokémon with high catch rates (i.e. those who are easy to catch), the improvement is much less.

Here are some numbers: (it means that the *Heavy Ball* is x-times as effective as a regular Pokéball)

> Dialga 2.3x
>   Kyogre 7x
>   Lugia 7.6x
>   Rayquaza 7.6x
>   Regirock 7.6x
>   Registeel 7.6x
>   Groudon 9x
>   Arceus 11x
>   Giratina 14.3x
>   Heatran 14.3x
>   Regigigas 14.3x

In short, a *Heavy Ball* is best thrown at a hard-to-catch heavy pokémon.

Unfortunately *Heavy Ball* can only be made with a Black Apricorn, it's a long process. However *Timer Balls* can be found in Goldenrod Store and you can buy as many as you want. I think this is the reason.

Source [Thonky](http://www.thonky.com/pokemon-heartgold-soulsilver/heavy-ball) and [Smogon](http://www.smogon.com/ingame/guides/capture_mechanics#ballrate_values).

Comment: I'm surprised at those multipliers larger than Groudon. When I checked in 5th gen, Groudon was the heaviest pokemon in the national dex (not sure if that still applies currently in 6th gen with Mega-Aggron since I don't have a 3DS)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts probably because Groudon's catch rate is 5, and not 3 like the others

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't matter if Groudon is the heaviest, it falls in the same category of [these pokemon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_weight#903.1_lbs._to_2204.4_lbs._.28409.7_kg_to_999.7_kg.29).

Comment: @Michaellogg In games prior to Pokémon ORAS, [Groudon has a catch rate of 5](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_catch_rate). This question asks about 4th gen.

Comment: @pinckerman Weird, I was specifically looking for that information, since I suspected as much, but couldn't find anything about it. I see it in the Trivia section on the Groudon page too, now. You'd think they would have put the note directly on the Catch Rate entry like they do with most things, but apparently not. All right then, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @Michaellogg They should. Also because Groudon page in other languages it's not updated yet.